# Struts2 parameters is coming null in action class

Tags: struts2

i am not able to get the value of the text entered in the textbox in jsp into my action class. below are my files. can anyone please help as this is very urgent.

my jsp is

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<body>
  <s:form action="login" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
    <s:submit type="button" id="submit" label="Submit"/>
    <s:reset id="reset" label="Reset"></s:reset>
  </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

my action class is

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.userName = username;
}


    public String execute(){
                System.out.println("the userName is "+this.getUserName());
            return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

and my struts.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
        <include file="struts-default.xml" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="core.login.LoginAction">
            <result  name="error">>/webpages/login/Error.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/webpages/home/Home.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: You're missing `<result name="input"> </result>`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors here? Does the call reach your action?

Answer (score 2):

Case-sensitivity is important.

```
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.userName = username;
}
```

Should be:

```
public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.userName = username;
}
```

Comment: Not related to this problem but there is an extra `>` after `<result  name="error">`

Comment: Due to the type of the problem I think Steven might have got it right here.

Answer (score 0):

In your struts.xml, you have written

```
class="core.login.LoginAction"
```

but you are not declaring any package in your Action class.
Also setter and getter method are of different names. Remember they are case-sensitive as said by Steven.
Try removing minor mistakes like an extra ">"

Answer (score 0):

In your textfield add value attribute like this:

```
<s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" value="${userName}" />
```

That directly maps it to member variable in action class.

Comment: This answer is wrong. a) you don't need to specify a value on Struts2 tags and b) you can't use EL in Struts2 tag attributes

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, 
to solve case sensitivity problem right click on code writing area and go to source -> Generate getter and setter method
It will add getter and setter method for selected member variables.